# Where to store dictionary data or function to be available in multiple Polymer elements?

Tags: polymer

I'm using Polymer to build an application that presents a data table. Every cell in the table contains a coded value.

I want that every time a user clicks on a cell, the value gets translated to a more descriptive tag.

#### Example:

```
|       Page        | Response |
|-------------------|----------|
| example.com/one   |      200 |
| example.com/two   |      200 |
| example.com/three |      500 |
| example.com/four  |      301 |
```

Then I click on the `301`:

```
|       Page        | Response |
|-------------------|----------|
| example.com/one   |      200 |
| example.com/two   |      200 |
| example.com/three |      500 |
| example.com/four  | Redirect |
```

The table is a `webpage-list` element that contains a `dom-repeat` template of `paper-item`s wrapped in a row element I've called like `webpage-item`.

I am creating a different element for any type of cell (in the example: one `response-field` element, then another could be `content-type-field` and so on).

Except, my table has several coded columns and the dictionaries are huge.

Where should I store the dictionary? I guess an app-scoped (global) dictionary object would be instantiated for every single cell, resulting in a massive resource leak.

Is there a way to provide a "translator" element to be called by reference by every cell? And... is this the right path to take?

Another path I am considering is letting the dictionary on the server, and then make REST calls every time I need a translation. But then, I would still need a translator element to handle the caching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [iron-meta](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-meta) element was built for this purpose. 
You can also build a custom more specialized element for this purpose. 
Each instance of iron-meta just provides access to a shared (static) container.

Comment: Thank you! That's great, it's just what I was looking for. But just to be sure... was that "doesn't" intended in your last sentence?

Comment: Right, that doesn't make much sense. I guess this was just a leftover from a dropped attempt to explain it. English isn't my native tongue ;-)